# ¿Como puedo separar un vector char?

Tags: c

Hola necesito hacer como un buscador donde el usuario ingresa una palabra "caramelo" y luego ingresa la letra "el" debe imprimir la palabras que buscas es "caramelo"

el problema es que el usuario debe ingresar  asi " caramelo|el" y no se como hacer eso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char cadena[30];
    char subCadena[15];
    int i = 0;

        printf("Bienvenido \n\n");

        printf("Introduce una palabra: >>\n");
            fgets(cadena, sizeof(cadena), stdin);

        printf("\nIntroduce las letras que recuerdas:>>\n");
            fgets(subCadena, sizeof(subCadena), stdin);

        cadena[strlen(cadena) -1] = '\0';
        subCadena[strlen(subCadena) -1] = '\0';

        for(i; (cadena[i] = toupper(cadena[i])); i++);
        for(i = 0; (subCadena[i] = toupper(subCadena[i])); i++);

        if(strstr(cadena, subCadena) != NULL){
        printf("\n\nla palabras que buscas es %s \n\n", cadena);
        }
       else{

        printf("\n\n no se encuentra \n\n");
            }
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Si el usuario ingresa "caramelo|el"... ¿se asume que únicamente hay que recordar una palabra y comprobar si el fragmento indicado está contenido en dicha palabra?

Comment: si asi mismo pero no se como recorrer  eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pretendes puedes recurrir a dos funciones:

- [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/): Esta funcion divide una cadena en base a unos delimitadores dados.
- [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/): Esta función localiza una subcadena dentro de otra.

Si las pones a trabajar juntas puedes conseguir algo como esto:

```
char buffer[100];
strcpy(buffer,"caramelo|el");
char* palabra = strtok(buffer,"|");
char* fragmento = strtok(NULL,"|");

if( strstr(palabra,fragmento) != NULL )
  puts("Fragmento encontrado\n");
else
  puts("No hay coincidencias\n");
```

La función `strtok` se usa para separar la palabra del fragmento a buscar, mientras que con `strstr` averiguamos si el fragmento se encuentra en la palabra inicial o no.

PD.: Ambas funciones se encuentran en la librería `string.h`

Comment: Gracias a sido de muchisima ayuda

Comment: Si esto soluciona tu duda, la comunidad te agradecería que la etiquetases como _"solución"_. Eso indicará a otros usuarios con dudas similares a la tuya saber que esta pregunta soluciona el problema planteado.

Comment: como puedo hacer eso soy nueva en la pagina

Comment: Te recomiendo seguir el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Ahí podrás conocer detalles interesantes sobre este portal